# Where to find resource ID #0x7f0800f0 in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I have got a crash with the cause -

***Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_splash.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800f0***

We have background_splash as XML file and one of the item is another drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

<item
    android:bottom="128dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/splash_logo_p4b_new_resized"
    android:gravity="center"></item>

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/blue_bottom_strip"
    android:gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"></item>
```

My question, If i want to more detail about the resource ID #0x7f0800f0, Is there a way to find and check.
Maybe with apk analyser or in some way?

Answer (score 1):

In `$projectRoot\app\build\intermediates\runtime_symbol_list`, there is `R.txt` file, which has all ID info.

Try to find what ID has 0x7f0800f0 in it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that following images available in the res/drawable folder.

```
 "@drawable/splash_logo_p4b_new_resized"
 "@drawable/blue_bottom_strip"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
​
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
​
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash_logo_p4b_new_resized"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    <item
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/blue_bottom_strip"
           android:gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

try this

Comment: Actually earlier it was put like your example only....still it gave the error.

Answer (score 0):

As I realized, your code compiles but in the runtime, you're getting that exception, so I assume there's something wrong with the Android Studio generating the R class. I suggest you `sync` the gradle and `clean` and `rebuild` the project. Even try to invalidate caches and resources.

Comment: Happens in the release build ..prod build for the users ... getting this report in the firebase crashlytics

Comment: Are you using proguard? If yes, maybe it's minifying something that it shouldn't.